# MySQL Order by another table's last row

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, where I want to get the table A's content, but ordered from table B's values. I order by 3 values (solved, reply_date and then date). But my problem is that it is not taking the last row from table B, so the result is not what I expect. This is my query so far.

```
SELECT user_tickets.user_ticket_id, user_tickets.user_id, solved, subject, user_tickets.date AS date, user_tickets_replies.date AS reply_date
FROM user_tickets 
INNER JOIN user_tickets_replies ON user_tickets.user_ticket_id=user_tickets_replies.user_ticket_id && user_tickets.user_id = user_tickets_replies.user_id 
GROUP BY user_tickets.user_ticket_id 
ORDER BY solved ASC, reply_date DESC, date DESC
LIMIT 200
```

How do I get the LAST reply_date from user_tickets_replies?

Comment: This is MySQL + innoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, but I ended up using PHP instead. Using this query to get all the tickets:

```
SELECT user_ticket_id, user_id, solved, subject, date FROM user_tickets ORDER BY solved ASC, date DESC LIMIT 200
```

Then adding all the data to an array and sorting it with this:

```
usort($tickets, function($a, $b) {
    $solved = $a['solved'] - $b['solved'];
    if ($solved) return $solved; 
    return $a['replied'] > $b['replied'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have many tickets, of which some have more than one reply. You wish to sort by the latest (most recent) `reply_date`, but you find that the sorting is not correct.

There are two ways that I can think of solving this, depending on whether you want your query to return all the `reply_date`s for a given ticket, or just the most recent. The first option would be to change your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY solved ASC, MAX(user_tickets_replies.date) DESC, user_tickets.date DESC
```

This keeps the `reply_date` column in its current state, but only uses the greatest date for sorting purposes.

The second is to change your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ..., MAX(user_tickets_replies.date) AS reply_date
```

This changes the `reply_date` column to include one value per row in `user_tickets` instead of one value per row in `user_tickets_replies`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i am trying to do. And the second option did the trick. However, I forgot to mention that I also want to check if the last ticket reply was from the ticket creator. I have ** user_tickets.user_id = user_tickets_replies.user_id** right now in the **ON**, so I guess I have to remove that. But then it will also sort by the last admin-reply. And I only want to sort by creator-reply.

Answer (score 0):

The last reply date should be the Max(user_tickets_replies.date) right?

I would join in a sub select of just the data you want to sort by.

```
inner join (SELECT user_ticket_id, max(date) as reply_date FROM user_tickets_replies group by 1 order by 2 desc limit 200) sorted_tickets
```

and then

```
 order by sorted_tickets.reply_date
```